# How to solve MME

Tags: regression, mixed-model, variance, predictive-models, sas

I have spent an entire day trying to figure out how to solve these mixed model equations without any luck. I am therefore reaching out to this community. The assignment is as follows:

> Using the information in the table below, solve the mixed model
> equations (MME), compute the prediction error variance [V(P.E.)] for
> the next four models and, in the end, tabulate the results [solutions
> and V(P.E.)], then compare and discuss them.

[image: tabel of sire progeny means and number of offspring in brackets]

This is what I have figured out so far:

[image: This is what I have figured out so far]

I cannot seem to figure out how to calculate $G$, because I don´t know the value og $\sigma^2_e$, $\sigma^2_h$ and $\sigma^2_s$. Furthermore I do not know how to do the solving in SAS. Should I use the PROC MIXED function, and if so, how?

Comment: I don't use SAS, but I believe PROC MIXED is used when you have the raw data. Here you are working with summary statistics data. I assume that you would have to calculate parameter estimates by hand or use another approach.